# Redirect page and auto-open some lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this address: www.example.com/teste123

On this page i have this redirect:

```
<%
response.redirect "http://www.example.com/index.asp?teste=true"
%>
```

So what i want? I want if the user access these address www.example.com/teste123, and the page redirect back to the root of the website, this open some lightbox with another file inside...

i found this script to get the variable on URL:

```
function getUrlVars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}   

var XXX = getUrlVars()["teste"];
```

these are return to me `true` .. so this is right... but.. how to open some lightbox only if the var `XXX` is equal "true" ?

Comment: what do you mean by "some" lightbox ? you have the value, test if it is true then open your LB ? whats the problem ?

Comment: i don't know how to try... i'm using this `if (clube == "teste"){
   alert("bazinga!)
 }` but dont work ... i need to put this inside some function??

Comment: what is clube ? just do if (XXX) { alert('I need to open my LB here') } and repace the alert by a call to the open/show method of the lightbox you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tutorials on lightboxes you can google and pick from. This is the basic logic (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
<div class="my_light_box" style="display:none;">Hi.</div>

<script>
if(getUrlVars()["test"])
{
    $('.my_light_box').show();
}

function getUrlVars(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}   
</script>
```